# Site offline: The mysql error was: Access denied for user '[cpaneluser]'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: database

I'm somewhat new to drupal and I was handed a broken site to take a look at it.

The site is hosted on a godaddy shared hosting site. I'm not sure what they did to it but it is unable to connect to it's database anymore. I verified that the setttings.php has the correct credentials (it did not but it does now) but it still cant connect. The url is [desoto.org](http://www.desoto.org/).

I'm getting the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/desotoorg/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: path in /home/desotoorg/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 63

The mysql error was: Access denied for user 'desotoorg'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

What is odd is that the user desotoorg is the cpanel system user and not the user that I have configured to access the drupal database.

Any ideas as to what would cause this? Godaddy seems to thing that everything is running fine and that cpanel has all of the right permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Try writing a simple script that connects to the db only (without Drupal) and put it on your server and see if the same problem pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your sites/default/settings.php file for a line like this:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://dbname:dbuserpassword@localhost/appname';
```

This line describes the url used by drupal to connect to the database used by drupal (the syntax above assumes mysql). Make sure that the password is correct and matches the latest password for the database user. These passwords often change when a site is compromised and then the site stops working.